# Firefox - The address wasn’t understood

Tags: apt, firefox, 17.10

I just install ubuntu 17.10 and trying to install `gnome tweak` through `apt://gnome-tweak-tool` but I get the following error

```
The address wasn’t understood
    Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (apt) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

You might need to install other software to open this address.
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

thanks

Comment: Could you open a terminal window, and type the command `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` and paste the results into your question?

Comment: This command installed gnome tweak. Thanks for sharing. Now i want to install now ubuntu-restricted-extras trough apt://ubuntu-restricted-extras and apt://arc-theme among others an get the same error, any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Changing answer slightly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answers have suggested workarounds, and not a proper fix, so I am sharing what worked for me.

1. Go to `about:config` in your Firefox browser
2. Right-click -> New -> Boolean -> Name: `network.protocol-handler.expose.apt` -> Value -> false
3. Try opening an apt:// link (if you type in yourself, it searches for it on Google). It will show a pop-up, select AptUrl, and tick the option to remember it.

[Video Tutorial for beginners](https://youtu.be/Z6K2F2n5mmU)

Comment: Nice solution!  Where did you find a reference to it?

Comment: Right solution!

Comment: @user615274 Kindly Accept this answer :)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I think it is the [Firefox Documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol)

Answer (score 2):

To install gnome-tweak

`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

To install restricted-extras

`sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

To install arc-theme

`sudo apt install arc-theme`

Something has broken in one of the usual methods for installing software.  The link that you have posted *should* open the Ubuntu Software program and initiate installation, but obviously does not.

As a good learning experience, there are a lot of well written answers on this website which can be searched by ["How to install sofware"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+install+software)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am getting the links from this post http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: If these answers are helping, please check the Accepted (check mark) icon on the question!

Comment: `sudo apt install arc-theme` instead of `sudo apt-install arc-theme`

Comment: @user615274 fixed type - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try doing `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` instead ?